# same input twice not to be entered twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making program that builds a shopping list for a user. It should
repeatedly ask the user for items until they enter 'end' and then it should print the list. If the user has already added an item it should be ignored the next time. I got the problem with the last part where it should ignore the duplicate.I am also required use 'continue' but no idea how to implement to my code.

```
shoppingListVar = []
while True:
    item = input("Enter your Item to the List: ")
    shoppingListVar.append(item)
    if item in item:
        print("you already got this item in the list")
    if item == "end":
        break
print ("The following elements are in your shopping list:")
print (shoppingListVar)
```

Comment: You're close... you need to check if the item is in the list *before* appending it and then add the `continue` to that `if` statement...

Comment: hmm I still cant get it right, `if item in item: ` is well written code ?

Comment: I think you meant `if item in shoppingListVar` instead of `if item in item`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `if item in shoppingListVar:`.

```
shoppingListVar = []
while True:
    item = input("Enter your Item to the List: ")
    if item == "end":
        break

    if item in shoppingListVar:
        print("you already got this item in the list")
        continue

    shoppingListVar.append(item)

print ("The following elements are in your shopping list:")
print (shoppingListVar)
```

This code checks for the sentinel value ('end') first before appending the new item to the list, if it is not already present therein.

If the order of the shopping list does not matter, or you are going to sort it anyway, you could use a `set` instead of a `list`. That will take care of duplicates and you won't need to check for them, just use `shopping_list.add(item)` (and initialise with `shopping_list = set()`)

```
shopping_list = set()
while True:
    item = input("Enter your Item to the List: ")
    if item == "end":
        break
    shopping_list.add(item)

print("The following elements are in your shopping list:")
print(shopping_list)
```

Comment: I had to use list for that practice exercise but i keep set in mind thanks

Comment: @user3077730: fair enough.

Comment: @user3077730: if use of `continue` is a requirement, you can add that whenever you detect a duplicate entry. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better using an if-elif-else structure in your code to deal with the 3 different expected conditions

Also you need to change the `if item in item:` to `if item in shoppingListVar:`

```
shoppingListVar = []
while True:
    item = input("Enter your Item to the List: ")
    if item in shoppingListVar:
        print("you already got this item in the list")
    elif item == "end":
        break
    else:
        shoppingListVar.append(item)
print ("The following elements are in your shopping list:")
print (shoppingListVar)
```

Comment: ohh i see, I tried `if item in shoppingListVar:` but i dint have an  if-elif-else structure so maybe thats why it didnt work. Is there any chance to throw `continue` statement ? i have no idea how that works